# Sorting Progress from User Data in Jade using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, pug

I currently have an issue.. I'm trying to sort progress bars from least to greatest in the Jade template system.

Basically the way the script is currently setup on the jade end is just grabbing data from a REST api using node-rest-client, then I interpret the data in the Jade template.

I currently have the spells loaded, the progress bars are working, but I've been trying to sort it but to no avail.

Is there a way I can use something like `Array.prototype.sort()` with this sort of thing?

Here is the profile code:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  if !Player.Sorted
    p
    | You are looking @ data for #{Player.Username}
  else
    .row
        .col-md-4
            img(src="http://localhost:3009/image/" + Uuid + "&hrh=-20&aa=true")
        .col-md-4
            p
                | #{Player.Firstname} #{Player.Lastname} is year 
                strong #{Player.Year}
                |  and has traveled 
                strong #{Highscore.Playtime}
                |  blocks!
            ul
                each Spell in Spells.Spells
                    - var spellc = Math.trunc(Spell.CastCount/5000*100)
                    if spellc > 100
                        .progress
                            span.progress-value #{Spell.Name.replace("_", " ").toLowerCase()} 100% - Mastered
                            .progress-bar.progress-bar-success(
                                role='progressbar', aria-valuenow='100', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100', style='width:100%')
                    else
                        .progress
                            span.progress-value #{Spell.Name.replace("_", " ").toLowerCase()} #{spellc}%
                            .progress-bar.progress-bar-success(
                                role='progressbar', aria-valuenow=''+spellc+'', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100', style='width:' + spellc + '%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, `Array.prototype.sort()` will do the trick as you suggested.

If I got it right, you want to sort by `Spell.CastCount`, right? In that case, this should do the trick if performed on the Array right after retrieving it from the server, in the script:

```
Spells.sort(function(spell1, spell2) {
        return spell1.CastCount - spell2.CastCount;
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate this into the Jade template?

Comment: @BrandonPalmer I don't think so, but you can sort the array as you retrieve it from the API

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. It's literally as you said.